# Select data from row that meets the condition below that row

Tags: python, if-statement

I am looking how to create an if function that will select a row above another row where ColumnX is equal to the number 13.

Here is the code I have

```
if df.attrib.get("Column_Name") in ['13']:
```

I know this means that if  column name "Column_Name" = 13 then ...
but I want it to be if "Column_Name" 1 row below is equal to 13 then ...

Comment: Sorry but could you explain what do you mean by this sentence "but I want it to be if Column_Name 1 row below is equal to 13,14,15"

Comment: I guess to simplify it I want to select the row above another row where a column is equal to 13

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide an [mre] - which should include example data (emphasis on minimal). [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) (Pandas User guide).

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple Pandas Condition:

```py
import pandas as pd
# i created my own dataframe for testing
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':[1,2,13,4,5,13,6]})

# use simple condition to get the index of the element then access the element by index
df.iloc[df[df["numbers"]==13].index-1]
```

+output:

```
    numbers
1   2
4   5
```

Comment: thank you. What if I wanted to include the row with 13 along with the 3 rows above

Answer (score 0):

You can find the columns using pandas [.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function and a [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'condition':[1,3,4,3,2,13,3]})
>>> df
           condition
0          1
1          3
2          4
3          3
4          2
5         13
6          3
>>> df["condition_rolled"] = df['condition'].shift(-1)
>>> df
           condition  condition_rolled
0          1               3.0
1          3               4.0
2          4               3.0                                                                                                                               3          3               2.0
4          2              13.0
5         13               3.0
6          3               NaN
>>> df.loc[(df["condition_rolled"] == 13.0)]
           condition  condition_rolled
4          2              13.0
```